# File download not working in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to mvc4 . I used the below code to download file from server to client in the controller:

```
public ActionResult IndexSpecification(int option_id)
{
    int cat = (int)Session["category_Name"];
    int prod = (int)Session["product_ID"];
    int user = (int)Session["logged_in"];
    string twoinone = cat + "_" + prod; 
    f1 = Download(twoinone);
    return f1;
}
```

where  Download function is:

```
public FileResult Download( string twoinone)
{
    var webClient = new WebClient();   
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Download"), "a.rar"));
    string fileName = "Tellersoft.rar";
    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
}
```

The call to the controller is from ajax :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: base_url + '/Options/IndexSpecification',
    data: { option_id : 2 },
    //dataType: 'json', encode: true,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {     
        console.log(data);   
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (typeof (console) != 'undefined') {
            alert("oooppss");
        } else { 
            alert("something went wrong");
        }
    }
});
```

But downloading not working .not even returning any error. Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: base_url + '/Options/IndexSpecification',
    data: { option_id : 2 },
    //dataType: 'json', encode: true,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (typeof (console) != 'undefined') {
            alert("oooppss");
        } else {
            alert("something went wrong");
        }
    }
});
```

In your ajax request in success block you have to write this code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:'/Home/Download',
    data: { option_id: 2 },
    //dataType: 'json', encode: true,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
        window.location = '/Home/Download?option_id=2';
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (typeof (console) != 'undefined') {
            alert("oooppss");
        } else {
            alert("something went wrong");
        }
    }
});
```

you have to set your option id value globally and declare it in success section...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqAQB.png)

Comment: please try to format your code properly...